# Table placement and improved formatting

Tags: tables, formatting, threeparttable

I am trying to display a rather large table within our file. However, the table jumps to a new page while it looks like there is plenty of space on the previous page.

The code:

```
\chapter{Results}

\begin{sidewaystable}[htb] \centering
\begin{threeparttable}[t]
\setlength\tabcolsep{12pt}
\caption{Parameter point estimates, standard errors, \& log-likelihoods}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllllllll@{}}
\toprule\toprule
& G(1,1) & N-G(1,1) & Q-G(1,1) & $t$-G(1,1) & R-G(1,1) & L-RG(1,1) & LL-RG(1,1) & $t$-GAS(1,1) \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\omega$}                        &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\alpha$}                        &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\beta$}                         &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\nu$}                           &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\delta$}                        &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\gamma$}                        &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\xi$}                           &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\varphi$}                       &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\tau_1$}                       &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\tau_2$}                       &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\sigma_u$}                     &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$l(\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}})$} &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &
\\ \bottomrule\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft] \footnotesize
    \item[1] G($1,1$) denotes the GARCH model, L-RG($1,1$) and LL-RG($1,1$) are the Realized GARCH model with linear and log-linear specification, respectively. The other abbreviations are evident.
    \item[2] Numbers in parentheses are standard errors.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Would be great if I could receive a solution to this problem and maybe also some feedback on how to improve the overal formatting of the table.

Thanks!

Best,
Sean

Comment: sidewaystable always creates a new page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAICT, there's no reason for typesetting the table in landscape format. Portrait format should be fine unless the text block of your document is unusually narrow. The following solution employs a `tabular*` environment to make the table occupy the full width of the text block. Oh, and it doesn't insert a vertical bar after the first column, but it does insert a bit of whitespace after every third or fourth row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report} % select a suitable document class
\usepackage{rotating,threeparttable,booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,bm}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set suitable page parameters

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{3} % just for this example
\chapter{Results}

\begin{table}[htb] 
\begin{threeparttable}[t]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out inter-column whitespace
\caption{Parameter point estimates, standard errors, \& log-likelihoods}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{c}}
\toprule
& G(1,1) & N-G(1,1) & Q-G(1,1) & $t$-G(1,1) & R-G(1,1) & L-RG(1,1) & LL-RG(1,1) & $t$-GAS(1,1) \\ \midrule
$\omega$  &        &          &          &          &          &          &          &          \\
$\alpha$  &        &          &          &          &          &          &          &          \\
$\beta$   &        &          &          &          &          &          &          &          \\
\addlinespace
$\nu$     &        &          &          &          &          &          &          &          \\
$\delta$  &        &          &          &          &          &          &          &          \\
$\gamma$  &        &          &          &          &          &          &          &          \\
$\xi$     &        &          &          &          &          &          &          &          \\
\addlinespace
$\varphi$ &        &          &          &          &          &          &          &          \\
$\tau_1$  &        &          &          &          &          &          &          &          \\
$\tau_2$  &        &          &          &          &          &          &          &          \\
\addlinespace
$\sigma_u$&        &          &          &          &          &          &          &          \\
$l(\hat{\bm{\theta}})$ & &    &          &          &          &          &          &          \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\smallskip
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft] 
\footnotesize
\item[1] G($1,1$) denotes the GARCH model, L-RG($1,1$) and LL-RG($1,1$) 
  are the Realized GARCH model with linear and log-linear specification, 
  respectively. The other abbreviations are evident.
\item[2] Numbers in parentheses are standard errors.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this can work, or you can downscale to fit

```
    \chapter{Results}

%\begin{table}[htb] \centering
\rotatebox{90}{%
\scalebox{0.85}{
\begin{threeparttable}[t]
\setlength\tabcolsep{12pt}
\caption{Parameter point estimates, standard errors, \& log-likelihoods}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllllllll@{}}
\toprule\toprule
& G(1,1) & N-G(1,1) & Q-G(1,1) & $t$-G(1,1) & R-G(1,1) & L-RG(1,1) & LL-RG(1,1) & $t$-GAS(1,1) \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\omega$}                        &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\alpha$}                        &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\beta$}                         &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\nu$}                           &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\delta$}                        &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\gamma$}                        &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\xi$}                           &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\varphi$}                       &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\tau_1$}                       &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\tau_2$}                       &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$\sigma_u$}                     &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &            \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{$l({\theta})$} &        &          &          &          &          &           &            &
\\ \bottomrule\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft] \footnotesize
    \item[1] G($1,1$) denotes the GARCH model, L-RG($1,1$) and LL-RG($1,1$) are the Realized GARCH model with linear and log-linear specification, respectively. The other abbreviations are evident.
    \item[2] Numbers in parentheses are standard errors.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
}}
%\end{table}
```

Comment: Using `\scalebox` in combination with a table will lead to inconsistent font sizes.